# Would it be possible for the page to remember the depth to which a person has expanded their answer textbox on a particular response?

Tags: feature-request

I would find it a great convenience if the page could remember how far I had dragged open the text-box for a response I had given. When I am working with a strange (new to me) keyboard, I tend to make a lot of typing errors because of muscle memory, and there are some really weird keyboard shortcuts that create havoc when my ring finger or pinky goes astray and hits the CTRL key rather than the SHIFT key; and so I find myself needing to go back and correct some rather bizarre typos. And each time I save a change, the textbox reverts to its default size. It's not a big deal, but if it's something that would be possible using the ResizeObserver API and local storage, it would greatly improve the editing uxperience for me.

Comment: Related: [Text box size, displayed post and general layout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284201/323179) (main meta)

Comment: Is this about UI design for web browsers and HTML layout in general or about the very particular website of ELU on StackExchange? @Laurel is this on-topic for ELU meta?

Comment: @Mitch It's a request for SE to change the height of the the textarea when editing, so yes it's on topic here. It would also be on topic for Meta Stack Exchange. (The chance of getting a change like this made by SE, however, is close to none.)

Comment: Yes, to *remember* the height the user has chosen when expanding the textbox using the drag-corner.

Comment: That other question cited by @Laurel is an alternative approach, where SE would allow users to set a default height for each SE-subsite.   My suggested approach would be at the *question* level. If I had dragged the textbox larger on a particular question, SE would remember that height setting, for me, for that question, when edit mode is entered by me.  SE knows when the visitor is the answerer, and so the algorithm would be **when a user goes to edit an answer they've given, set the textbox height to *stored-height-setting***.  *ResizeObserver* API gives real-time info on the height-setting.